# Display JSON data from external API

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to sort out my knowledge about JSONP. I dont know how to make callback to external API

```
class MyClass
{
    private $_id = $_POST['id'];
    public get_name()
    {
        $id = $this->_id;
        $request = 'http://external.sever.com/api.php?operation=get_name&id='.$id.'&callback=?';
    }
}
```

Let's assume, this API works properly, and callback is like: {name:'Kamil'} or something like this.

And now comes the javascript code

```
$.ajax({ url: GET_REQUEST_FROM_MYCLASS, dataType: 'jsonp' }).done(function(data) {SEND_DATA_AS_$_POST_OR_ANOTHER_PHP_VAR});
```

how to put php variable in javascript and then output $.ajax send to server as POST variable?

Comment: You are fetching the data from client. Do yo want to send it to your server? Or you want to get it in the backend before rendering your page?

Comment: I want to print it by var_dump to know structure of object.

Comment: In your example code you are fetching the data from client (browser) AFTER php code has finished running and returned the response (code above). On this stage you can not run php commands. You can "console.log(data);" to see it in browser's console.